# how to change the ActionBar Tab text color with one line layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

There are two line layout,look at the `ActionBar` Tab, the text Color is blue;

[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B8rKhm-CIAIGFiv.png]

and this is one line layout,texColor is white,How could you make it ?

[image]

Comment: in wide screen the tabs will move to action bar automatically

Comment: @y.feizi I know that, but i don't know when it happens, i want change the text color

Comment: no need to know it ! only design your layout for wide screens in laout-land folder ! android detect it automatically

Comment: @y.feizi on my tablet(2048 × 1536p, 7.9in), laout-land and  laout-port are both one line layout.

Comment: you must google two things ! first : how to detect the screen size , second how to change the text color of action bar !

Comment: @y.feizi i change the text color in theme.xml : Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText ,and i really don't know what dpi is one line and what dpi is two lines. I can change the tab text color in my activity(onCreate),but I dont know when change it.

Comment: its better to ask it in a new question and explain it complete ! i dont know too , sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 To change the Tab Style,you cannot use `actionBar.newTab().setText(xxx)`，because you cannot fetch the TextView,so you must create a TextView,then use `actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(tabView)`;

```
private TextView createTab(int titleText) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(this,null,R.attr.actionBarTabTextStyle);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    textView.setText(titleText);
    return textView;
}
```

2 Look at the `R.attr.actionBarTabTextStyle` attribute,you must write a line in attrs.xml

```
//attrs.xml
<attr name="actionBarTabTextStyle" format="reference"/>
```

It is a reference of styles,in styles/xml or theme.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

3 create a Tab and add it to ActionBar:

```
// MainActivity
TextView tabView=createTab(tabTitle);
ActionBar.Tab actionBarTab=actionBar.newTab();
actionBarTab.setCustomView(tabView).setTabListener(this)
actionBar.addTab(actionBarTab);
```

4 ActionBar have a private field:mHasEmbeddedTabs,when in one line it is true,other is false,so just fetch this field's value.

```
private boolean mHasEmbeddedTabs =true;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        Field field = actionBar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mHasEmbeddedTabs");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        this.mHasEmbeddedTabs=field.getBoolean(actionBar);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

5 Now I can change the Tab Text Color when the actionbar and tab in one line

```
if(this.mHasEmbeddedTabs){
   tabView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}
```